# Get User Location by Marking on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

ALL

i wanna developing window contains map and allow user to mark his location and get longitude and latitude based on the marked location

any one has a suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use google map v3 for this purpose..
Try this code, it creates a marker where the user clicks on the map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Google Maps</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });
        map.panTo(position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thaaaaaanks alot sir, It wooks well... forgive me i tried to vote for your post but it requires 15 reputation, so thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

you will be requried to use maps click event to get lat/lag.
check below code for same.

```
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latLng)
        {
            // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
            document.getElementById("latFld").value = latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("lngFld").value = latLng.lng();
//code for adding marker
//post/ajax call to save location in Database

        });
```

Comment: That looks like API v2 code, which is deprecated and will stop working later this year.